# How can I do calculations inside a for loop with echo bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

My code

```
for ((i=1 ; i < $words2 + 1 ; i++)) ; 
do
  printf '%s %s %s\n' '<text x="30" y="10">'$i'</text>' | sed 's/ *$//' 
done
```

and then I get as output

```
<text x="30" y="10">'$1'</text>
<text x="30" y="10">'$2'</text>
<text x="30" y="10">'$3'</text>
```

But I want to change something
I want to add + 20 to 30 in every line so It my output changes like this

```
<text x="30" y="10">'$1'</text>
<text x="50" y="10">'$2'</text>
<text x="70" y="10">'$3'</text>
```

I have tried to do calculations but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: The code you posted cannot produce the output you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Like this:

```
for ((i=1, j=30 ; i < 10, j<=70 ; i++, j+=20)); do
    printf '<text x="%d" y="10">"$%d"</text>\n' $j $i
done
```

### Output

```
<text x="30" y="10">"$1"</text>
<text x="50" y="10">"$2"</text>
<text x="70" y="10">"$3"</text>
```